# importing from local directory

Tags: c#

I am having difficulties importing from project directory. Here is my code:

```
FileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
file.InitialDirectory = @"";
file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
file.RestoreDirectory = true;
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && this.mAT != null)
{
    if (file.FileName != String.Empty || file.FileName != null) 
    return this.mAT.importFromLexiconFile(file.FileName);
}
else return false;
return false;
```

How can I import a file from a local directory using a directory as a text like `something.txt` instead of looking for the file in `FileDialog`?

Comment: What is the path to the file? Where are you setting the path?

Comment: "...did not work" this is the _least_ descriptive you can be. What was the exception?

Comment: The starting directory were the `MainWindow.xaml` is located

Comment: The window did start but the content did not appear.

Comment: Tell me the absolute path of the file. For example: `C:\Some\Test.txt`.

Comment: What happens if you change `file.InitialDirectory = @"";` to `file.InitialDirectory = @".";`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the directory from where the project was started using:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Or you can get the location that your `.exe` is located in using:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

At runtime, this would be something like:

> C:\projects\myapplication\myproject\bin\Debug\

Here's how you can find your file, and some different things you can do with it. Not sure exactly what you want to do:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // The directory to search for the file
    var searchPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

    // The name of the file we're searching for
    var fileName = "MyFile.txt";

    // Get the first match
    var theFile = Directory.GetFiles(searchPath, fileName).FirstOrDefault();

    // If the match is not null, we found the file
    if (theFile != null)
    {
        // Output some information about the file
        Console.WriteLine("Found the file: {0}", fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("The full path of the file is: {0}", theFile);

        // If it's a text file, here's one way to get the contents
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(theFile);

        Console.WriteLine("The contents of the file are:{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, 
            fileContents);

        // If you need detailed info about the file, or 
        // want to write to it, create a FileInfo object
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(theFile);

        // Output some detailed information about the file
        Console.WriteLine("The file was created on: {0}", fileInfo.CreationTime);
        Console.WriteLine("The file was last modified on: {0}", 
            fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
        Console.WriteLine("The file attributes are:");
        Console.WriteLine(" - ReadOnly: {0}", 
            Convert.ToBoolean(fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
        Console.WriteLine(" - Hidden: {0}", 
            Convert.ToBoolean(fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden));
        Console.WriteLine(" - System: {0}", 
            Convert.ToBoolean(fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.System));
    }
}
```

Comment: but then how do I find my file?

Comment: try `Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.txt");` or if you want a single file you know the name of: `new FileInfo("sometext.txt");` or to open it `File.Open("somtext.txt", FileMode.Open);`

Comment: Added some more information. There are many ways to read and write from a file, so if you still have a specific question, it might warrant another question on this site (although do search around, though...it's a common topic)